# How get size of a Jpeg?

Tags: delphi, jpeg

How can I find the image dimensions of a JPEG with reading the entire file?(I just want to get the image size.)
.

.

My project is stream picture on network by broadcast `UDP` pocket;

I want capture webcam to `TJPEGImage` var and check for image size and when the size of picture is bigger than X byte (X is max pocket size of `UDP` pocket on network), then break  it apart  to smaller size image and broadcast  them to `UDP` pocket to network.

Uses of `TMemoryStream` or `TFileStream` is very slow for huge process of image;

Uses of `TBitmap` var create bigger bitmap size and slower to broadcast.

Uses of `TMemoryStream`  compress is useful but breaking `TMemoryStream`  to small size pocket and reassembling them  on destination system is impossible because dropping some of pocket on transfer base on `UDP` protocol.

So I need a fast cod to get size of capture `TJPEGImage`.

Sample cod:

```
.
.
jp:=TJPEGImage.Create;
jp.assign(….)     //(get picture from webcam)
if jp.size >X then
begin
  …… breaking jp apart to small size (C = small size picture count)
  for I := 1 to C do
    …… broad cast jp(i) to network base on UDP pocket;
End
Else
  …… broad cast jp to network base on UDP pocket;
```

Comment: this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209076/how-to-get-dimensions-of-image-file-in-delphi)  refers to dimensions. However, I need the size of the image size based on the byte.

Comment: What do you mean? Size of file?

Comment: You will have to explain exactly what you mean.

Comment: Perhaps you want to know how to find the size of a file? I suggest that you make some effort to explain.

Comment: Save it to a memory stream and split it from there. You have to save it. You can't skip that bit.

Comment: who can help me?

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for: https://github.com/bitbank2/imageinfo

Comment: This file is not saved on the hard disk. So I cannot use the TFile (and TMemoryStream is slow).I want to know the size of this image in the Timage variable  (Based on byte) .